# Early page fault is triggered with IF flag cleared, but how is that possible?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm reading the latest linux source code and I find that early page fault interrupt is triggered even if instruction `cli` is executed and IF flag is cleared. But how is that possible? Is it non-maskable? If so, what's the relationship with NMI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Term "maskable" is applicable only to interrupts of type **IRQ** (Interrupt ReQuest), which are also referred as *Hardware Interrupts*.

However, *page fault* interrupt is not an IRQ, but of **Exception** type. Such types of interrupts cannot be masked by definition.

About classification of interrupts see e.g. here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt.

---

Think about: what should CPU do, if *page fault*, caused by an instruction's execution, *could be masked*? In that case, CPU would unable to perform the instruction and to proceed futher.

Opposite: if timer IRQ is masked, CPU can proceed as normal.